# Discord.py random member picking bot

Tags: python, discord.py

Hi im making a random member picking bot

```
@bot.command()
async def 이벤트뽑기(ctx, count=1):
author = ctx.message.author
if not ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_roles:
    return await ctx.send(f'{author.mention}, 권한이 없으십니다. 지속적으로 사용시 밴 사유에 해당되므로 주의해주세요!')
guild = bot.get_guild(756707533384843357)
results = [ member for member in guild.members if member.bot == False]
if count > len(results) or count <= 0:
    await ctx.send('꺼져')
    return
embed5 = discord.Embed(
    description=f"첫 번째 당첨자를 발표하겠습니다!",
    inline=True, color=0xfe8686) 
await ctx.send(embed=embed5)
#choices = random.choice(results)
results = []
role = ctx.guild.get_role(770314023136395264)
for member in guild.members:
    if role in member.roles:
        await ctx.send("축하합니다 f'{member.mention} 굿")
        embed6 = discord.Embed(description=f'**당첨자분들은 ! ANDY#1000 에게 디엠 부탁드립니다.**\n\n{", ".join(results)}/{member}님 **당첨** 축하드립니다!', color=0x86f4fe)
        embed6.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/650916786111250432/773144216742002698/704862766770552883.png")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed6)
```

So this is my code [but it keeps coming 5-6 result not just one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJvtG.png)

How could i fix this error

Comment: It's difficult to understand the problem.. can you clarify in English?

Comment: Check how many calls `for member in guild.members:` performs.